# Typescript equivalent of List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

In the API I am using, the response has `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` data type which is written in C#.
It looks like this;

```
"MetaData": [
    {
      "key": "Name",
      "value": "John"
    }
  ]
```

Is there a built-in equivalent of this data type on Typescript that I can map while getting it in an interface

```
interface APIResponse {
    id: bigint;
    success : boolean;
    metaData : ?;
}
```

and how am I going to get the value part of the pair which key is **Name**

Comment: You mean like `type MetaData = {key : string, value : string}[];`?

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 ways to do this:

1. Create a new object, then use it:

```
interface MyKeyVal {
    key: string;
    value: string;
}

interface APIResponse {
    id: bigint;
    success: boolean;
    metaData: MyKeyVal[];
}
```

Here, it will be easier if you add new field after value, even if it's object instead of simple string.

2. Use map like `Map<string, string>`:

```
interface APIResponse {
    id: bigint;
    success: boolean;
    metaData: Map<string, string>[];
}
```

The key will not be `"Name"` but `"key"` as it's the string from your json

Comment: Not sure `Map` would quite work as there is nothing to prevent duplicate keys in `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use the Record type for this:

```js
type MyType = Record<string, string>[];

const myItems : MyType = [
  {
    "someKey": "someValue",
  }, 
  { 
    "someOtherKey": "someValue", 
    "andAnotherOne": "anotherOne" 
  }
]
```

See here for the record utility type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type

Your interface would look like this:

```
interface APIResponse {
    id: bigint;
    success : boolean;
    metaData : Record<string, string>;
}
```

You can also create more explicit record types by providing a more strict type in the generic `Keys` and `Type` types if you know what schema the API response uses.

> and how am I going to get the value part of the pair which key is Name

There is no built-in data type that allows you to get the value for the item with a key `Name`.

You can use something like:

```
const metaData = [
  {key: "Name", value: "Some Name"},
  {key: "Age", value: "18"}
]

const item = metaData.find(({key}) => key === "Name");
// item.value === "Some Name"
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: True. I misread his question. I've updated my answer to show how he can get the value of a list-item with a key property called Name.